# JWT token How to split claim and signature

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, token

In JWT token authentication, it is mentioned the "." is used for splitting the 3 parts of token (header, claim, signature). But in-case if my signature or encoded claim contains the "." it would be difficult  the exact content of 3 section. Anybosy came across this situation or what is the way to handle it?

I generated signature using HMACSHA256(encoded json claim), but I'm getting "." in middle of the signature data. when i concatenate all the 3 parts, i'm getting one extra "."

Comment: If the order of this 3 parts is header, claim and signature, you should know that after the second "." the rest is signature, right?

Comment: Yes, Header and Claims are Base64URLEncoder encoded content. My doubt is what if Header/Claims also contains  "."

Comment: From what I see they use *HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  secret)* on the official site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three parts of the JWT token are all [base64 encoded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and therefore will never contain a dot character.

Even if your claim or signature contains that character, after base64 encoding that part the dot will no longer appear in the output.